# Are $L^2$ and total variation-linked norms equivalent on this function space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, total-variation

Let $K > 0$. Let $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}^1([0,K], [-1,1] )$ be the space of $C^1$  functions $f : [0, K] \rightarrow [-1,1]$, such that $f(0)=0$. Let's use the norm:

$$||f||_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^K f(t)^2 d t}$$

and also the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation):

$$||f||_T = \int_0^K |f'(t)| d t$$

**Question: are there constants $a$ and $b$ such that:**

$$||f||_T \leq a ||f||_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad ||f||_2 \leq b ||f||_T$$

**for all functions $f \in \mathcal{C}$ ?**

---

Discrete analogous question:

Let $N > 0$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be the space of all sequences $(y_n)_{0 \leq n \leq N}$, with $-1 \leq y_n \leq 1$ for all $n$, and $y_0 = 0$. We use the norms:

$$||(y_n)||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^N y_(n)^2}$$

and

$$||(y_n)||_T = \sum_{n=1}^N |y(n)-y(n-1)|$$

Are there constants $c$ and $d$ such that:

$$||(y_n)||_T \leq c ||(y_n)||_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad ||(y_n)||_2 \leq d ||(y_n)||_T$$

for all sequences $(y_n) \in \mathcal{D}$ ?

Note:

- Ideally, the constants $a$, $b$ should be independant of $K$. The same for the discrete case.
- If not true in general on $\mathcal{C}$, would it be possible to find such inequalities on a subspace $\mathcal{C}^*$ of functions that have a limited bandwidth in high frequencies? (let's say the spectrum has no or few composant of frequency $f \geq f_0$; in my audio application: $f_0$ is $20 000$ Hz).

Comment: For the first one, consider $\sin (nx), n=1,2,\dots$ For the second one, consider $f$ a constant.

Comment: have a look at Poincare inequality and Sobolev inequalities which provide various integral norm estimates for the gradient and the original function.

Comment: @zhw. I forgot to mention (now edited, fixed in the question) the condition $f(0)=0$. So $f$ constant is necessarily the $0$ constant.

Answer (score 1):

For the second inequality:

$$\int_0^K f(t)^2\,dt = \int_0^K \left  (\int_0^t f'(s)\,ds\right)^2\,dt$$ $$ \le \int_0^K \left  (\int_0^t |f'(s)|\,ds\right)^2\,dt\le \int_0^K   \|f\|_T^2\,dt = K\|f\|_T^2.$$

Take square roots to see $\|f\|_2 \le \sqrt K \|f\|_T.$

Comment: That wasn't a good hint after all. I was thinking $\|f\|_T= (\int_0^K(f'(t))^2\,dt)^{1/2}.$ I changed my hint to just the one equality. This will give you the inequality, but with a constant depending on $K.$

Comment: Things only get larger if you put absolute values on the integrand. Then for each $t$ the square of the integral is $\le \|f\|_T.^2$ I'll let you work on it, and then if you don't get it i'll add more.

Comment: @Basj My answer in now a more complete solution.